# How do I get a random result from a preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, arrays

*(Sorry if the title is pretty useless)*

I have this function to get the first image from a random post in WordPress. This works great, but now I need it to select a random image from all the matches, rather than the first.
(I'm running this function in a query_posts loop to select the categories)

```
// Get first image in post
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

    //no image found display default image instead
    if(empty($first_img)){
        $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
    }

    // Or, show first image.
    return $first_img;
}
```

So, any ideas, links, tips & tricks on how to select a random result from the matches results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match everything, and then use [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random match.

Assuming you use the PREG_SET_ORDER flag with preg_match_all then to get a random link.

```
$randomImage = $matches[array_rand($matches)][0];
```

It is important to note that `array_rand()` returns a random key, not a random value.

Comment: That worked! For everyone else., here's the final code.
'// Get first image in post
function catch_that_image() {
 global $post, $posts;
 $first_img = '';
 ob_start();
 ob_end_clean();
 $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
 $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
 
 //no image found display default image instead
 if(empty($first_img)){
  $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
 }
 
 // Or, show first image.
 return $matches[1][array_rand($matches[1])];
}'

Comment: Well, I can't get code to display correctly on here. (UX error?)
Here's the final code, formatted well. http://kodery.com/119

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
// Get first image in post
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);

    //no image found display default image instead
    if(!$output){
        $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
    } //or get a random image
    else $first_img=$matches[1][array_rand($matches[1])];

    return $first_img;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns '0'.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to return a random key from the `$matches` array. You may need to change the format of the array you get from [`preg_match_all()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

You can use `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` then pass `$matches[$x]` to `array_rand()` - where `$x` is the match group you want (0 being the full match, 1 being the first subgroup). In this case `array_rand()` will return a key, and you can access the random data using `$matches[$x][$rand_key]`.

Alternatively, using `PREG_SET_ORDER`, you would pass `$matches` to `array_rand()`, then use the returned key to access any subgroup of the match. `$matches[$rand_key][$x]`

Note that you're not getting a random *value*, you're getting the array key to a random value. And as noted by others, you can simply use the `array_rand()` function directly when accessing the array, which is an easy cut/paste solution. However, I hope this longer explanation sheds light on what the code is doing.

Comment: Ah, sorry about my poor terminology. I've only been using PHP for a few months. I'll give your answer a try.